# how to download SVN tree

Tags: svn, sourceforge, redpin

i've read much document in google, im also installed tigris on my eclipse. but always out like this

> error validating location: "org.apache.subversion.javahl.clientexception: Bad URL passed to RA layer

you know how to download all files on this link http://sourceforge.net/p/redpin/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/

please i need that library, but in official website is so much corrupt, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect URL. Take a closer look at [the page](http://sourceforge.net/p/redpin/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/). The correct URL to checkout the repository is `http://svn.code.sf.net/p/redpin/code/trunk`.